# How to hide menu bar in second card in livecode

Tags: livecode

I have create menu bar in a card, I want that menu bar in current card only, but it appeared in main stack I don't know how it is solved.

Comment: Please post some of your code attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menubar is a group, which by default is created with its backgroundBehavior property enabled, and is probably added to all cards.  To remove the menubar from a card, select the menubar group, use the Inspector to disable the group's backgroundBehavior, and then choose Remove Group from the Object menu.  The menubar will be removed from the current card, but will remain on any other cards that contain the group.

Comment: Thankyou @Scott Rossi. I am beginner can you please give the step by step procedure of how to disable the group's backgroundBehavior.

Comment: Select the menubar group, view the Basic Properties pane of the Inspector palette, and uncheck the checkbox that reads backgroundBehavior.  You can also use the message box, by executing "set the backgroundBehavior of the selObj to false". The main reason to disable this property is so the menubar is not automatically added to any new cards you create in your stack.

Comment: Thankyou @Scott Rossi it's works.But I am created the menu bar in second card and my stack is a login page and the menu bar is appearing on stack . how I solve this any alternative method

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve. If the menubar is present on a card, you can remove it: Object menu > Remove Group.  If the menubar is NOT present on a card and you want it on the card: Object menu > Place Group > [the name of of your menubar].  If you don't want the menubar at all, delete the menubar group.